# Let $G$ be a group, $H\leq G$ and $K$ be a normal subgroup of $G$. Do we have $K$ a normal subgroup of $H$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

If we have that $H\leq G$ and $K\triangleleft G$ then, $\forall g\in G$ and $\forall k\in K$ we have $gkg^{-1}\in K$. In particular, $\forall h\in H$, we have $h\in G$ therefore, $ghg^{-1}\in K$, and $K\triangleleft H$. I'm hesitant that this argument is correct, however I do not see the mistake.

If someone could check this and give some guidance on its validity, I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: The subset condition is also vital. Otherwise you could similarly argue any normal subgroup is a normal subgroup of $\{e\}$, which may seem nonsense!

Comment: It is a matter of definitions. Usually $K \triangleleft H$ is taken to mean that $K \subseteq H$, and $h k h^{-1} \in K$ for all $h \in H$ and $k \in K$. However, your argument proves the correct statement that $K$ is invariant under the action of $H$ by conjugation.

Comment: Thanks @JustWandering , that was exactly the counterexample I was thinking.

Comment: Thanks @AndreasCaranti for the clarification!